# AIMP Format Settings Variables

Tags: windows, aimp

I'm trying to customize `AIMP`'s playlist by going to `Preferences > Playlist > Appearance` and `Format Settings` section.
I now have it set to `%IF(%R,%R - %T,%T)` which shows up as `Artist - Title` and I would like to expand it.
Where could I find the complete list of these variables without guessing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the **AIMP preferences**, then go to the **Sort by Template** tab in the playlist options. You'll find a template pattern. **Right clicking** on it will give you the list of all available variables. Then go to the appearance options in the **Playlist** tab and in the **Format Settings** box enter the desired pattern.

Comment: They shouldn't have this list so hidden

Comment: ok, but where are those like `%R`? Anybody knows? Is that a kind of standard?

Answer (score 1):

This seems not always to be working, found these variables by trying one by one:

1. %!
2. %Album
3. %AlbumArtist
4. %AlbumGain
5. %Artist
6. %BitRate
7. %BPM
8. %Channels
9. %Composer
10. %DiskNumber
11. %Duration
12. %FileCreatedDate
13. %FileCreatedTime
14. %FileDir
15. %FileFormat
16. %FileModifiedDate
17. %FileModifiedTime
18. %FileName
19. %FileParentDir
20. %FileSize
21. %Genre
22. %Index
23. %LastPlayDate
24. %LastPlayTime
25. %Lyrics
26. %Mark
27. %NewLine
28. %PlayCount
29. %Publisher
30. %Rating
31. %SampleRate
32. %Title
33. %TrackGain
34. %TrackNumber
35. %Year

Sub:

1. %Caps(A)
2. %Char(A)
3. %ExtractFileExt(A)
4. %Format(A, B)
5. %IF(A, B, C)
6. %IFEqual(A, B, C, D)
7. %IFGreater(A, B, C, D)
8. %IFGreaterOrEqual(A, B, C, D)
9. %Length(A)
10. %Low(A)
11. %Replace(A, B, C)
12. %StrCopy(A, B, C)
13. %StrPos(A, B)
14. %Up(A)